# How to get the total_count of friends? Facebook PHP-api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting the facebook user's number of friends. And I have no idea that how do I get the total_count.

Here is my code:

```
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try 
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
                $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];

    } else {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }

  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
    $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email,friends', $accessToken);

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
echo $accessToken;
 $user = $response->getGraphUser();
 $userInfo = $user->asArray();

 print_r($userInfo);
```

However, the print return these:

```
( [id] => 1234567890 
  [name] => lmc_john
  [email] => xxxxxxxx@hotmail.com 
  [friends] => Array ( ) )
```

And on the `Graph-api test tool`, it returns these:

```
{
    "id": "12345667890",
    "name": "lmc_john",
     "friends": {
       "data": [
        ],
        "summary": {
        "total_count": 89
    }
  }
}
```

So, how can I only get the friend total_count from this array?

Thx for helping

---

Finally, I found another way to get the total friend.

Here is my source codde:
https://github.com/capslock10/Get_facebook_total_friend/blob/master/getSession.php

Hope can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but maybe you can confirm whether its actually the case.  friends is showing you the data, which is rightfully empty since your app does not have permission to see friends.  However as described here, you can access the summary data for an edge.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphEdge/5.0.0

> Some endpoints and edges of Graph support a summary of data. If the
>   summary=true modifier was sent with a request on a supported endpoint
>   or edge, Graph will return the total count of results in the meta data
>   under $.summary.total_count. getTotalCount() will return that value or
>   null if it does not exist.

Comment: It returns a `friends array`, but it is a null object. I have no idea what is going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, typical issue. So the easy way to solve this is to decode the graphbody and not to use GetGraphUser as GetGraphUser does not send over the total_count.

Make sure to not use count() from "friends" as it only displays 
"Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher. total_count in summary represents the total number of friends, including those who haven't installed the app"

Here's the solution:

```
        $response = $response->getDecodedBody();
        $count = $response['friends']['summary']['total_count'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple, You can use method [count (array) = total_count]. refer [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

> echo count($userInfo['friends']);

Comment: I don't why, but it returns zero. is anything wrong of the permission? But the `access_token` can be use on the `Graph-api test tool` and return value correctly.

Comment: I'm sr. you can show me detail content of [friends] => Array (... ) )

Comment: It's object. $userInfo['friends']->data or $userInfo['friends']->total_count

Comment: got an error `get property of non-object`. I think facebook doesn't return the friend object.

Comment: This won't work, because `$userInfo['friends']` will include a maximum of 100 friends. It gets paginated beyond that.